# File format and player for synchronized dual video tracks?

Tags: software-recommendation

I often need to take a desktop capture video, and then simultaneously capture something else with a video camera; and then I want to watch the two synchronized recordings simultaneously.

For simplicity's sake, let's assume that both videos have been processed, so they have the same resolution (say 1280x720 pixels) and same framerate (say 25 fps) - and they have been synchronized, in the sense of being clipped, so they both start at the same "absolute" (or "calendar") time.

Is there a video file format, that would allow me to store these two videos as two independent streams - and is there a video player that could play this kind of format, that would allow for the following:

- At start, the player would show the two video streams *side-by-side* playing simultaneously - it might look like this in a 640x480 player window size (images generated from https://vioso.com/testpattern-generator/):

[image: side-by-side]

- Then, if I click a button or otherwise issue a command to the player, I can choose that I look only at the first stream, *while playback time continues* - so it would look like this in a 640x480 player window size:

[image: first-vid-only]

- ... and, if I again click a button or otherwise issue a command to the player, I can choose that I look only at the second stream, *while playback time continues* - so it would look like this in a 640x480 player window size:

[image: second-vid-only]

... and of course, I should be able to go back to the "side-by-side" view again (*while playback time continues*) by issuing a command (clicking a button) to the player.

Is there any video file format and video player (hopefully, cross-platform; JavaScript/web based would be fine too) that would support something like this?